# how to sort the time in a NSMutableArray in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

i'm having a set of Dictionaries in a NSMutableArray. now i want to sort ascending & Descending order by time here is my Array value.

```
(
    {
    StartTime = "09:00 AM";
    TravelsName = "ABC Travels";
},
    {
    StartTime = "07:30 AM";
    TravelsName = "XYZ Travels ";
},
    {
    StartTime = "06:45 PM";
    TravelsName = "GSP  Travels";
},
    {
    StartTime = "05:00 PM";
    TravelsName = "Madura  Travels";
},
    {
    StartTime = "12:45 AM";
    TravelsName = "MJT Travels";
},
    {
    StartTime = "12:45 PM";
    TravelsName = "OPR Travels";
},
    {
    StartTime = "01:00 AM";
    TravelsName = "VMS Travels";
}
)
```

Please help me i had sorted the set of NSDate inside the NSMutableArray 
by the below code

```
//To sort the Time Array
dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];

    NSMutableArray *dates = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:times.count];

    for (NSString *timeString in times)
    {
        NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:timeString];
        [dates addObject:date];
    }
    [dates sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

    NSMutableArray *sortedTimes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:dates.count];
    for (NSDate *date in dates)
    {
        NSString *timeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
        [sortedTimes addObject:timeString];
    }
```

but i don't know how to sort the Dictionary in the NSMutableArray help me.

Comment: NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"StartTime" ascending:YES];
sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:brandDescriptor];
sortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is best to use the sorting methods that are already provided in `NSArray`. Something like this should do:

```
NSArray *stortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *_Nonnull obj1, NSDictionary *_Nonnull obj2) {
        return [obj1[@"StartTime"] compare:obj2[@"StartTime"]];
}];
```

Or if the `StartTime` is still a string:

```
NSArray *stortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *_Nonnull obj1, NSDictionary *_Nonnull obj2) {
    return [[dateFormatter dateFromString:obj1[@"StartTime"]] compare:[dateFormatter dateFromString:obj2[@"StartTime"]]];
}];
```

To change the ascending/descending order you simply swap the `obj1` and `obj2` when used in the block:

```
return [obj2[@"StartTime"] compare:obj1[@"StartTime"]];
```

Comment: but in your code giving some error like Incompatible block pointer types sending NSComparisonResult((^)(NSdDictionary *_strong))to Parameter of type NSComparator .. So i tried...NSArray *stortedArray = [totDictArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary * obj1, NSDictionary *obj2)
        {
            return [[dateFormatter dateFromString:obj1[@"StartTime"]] compare:[dateFormatter dateFromString:obj2[@"StartTime"]]];
        }
        ];