# How can i create array in ascending order when multiple Dictionary in Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting, dictionary

I have one Array with Multiple Dictionary object with keys `Date` and `Type`
I want to arrange array in ascending order by `Date` key.

My Array Like this :

```
(
{
    Date = "06 September 2016";
    Type = Photo;
},
    {
    Date = "06 September 2016";
    Type = Video;
},
    {
    Date = "07 September 2016";
    Type = Photo;
},
    {
    Date = "07 September 2016";
    Type = Video;
},
    {
    Date = "06 September 2016";
    Type = Photo;
},
    {
    Date = "06 September 2016";
    Type = Photo;
},
    {
    Date = "07 September 2016";
    Type = Photo;
},
{
    Date = "01 October 2016";
    Type = Photo;
},
{
    Date = "06 September 2016";
    Type = Photo;
    }
)
```

Please Help me. How can i Arrange In ascending order by Date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to sort the time in a NSMutableArray in ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33779272/how-to-sort-the-time-in-a-nsmutablearray-in-ios)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `sortedArrayUsingComparator` like this way to sort date with String. First convert your date from String to `NSDate` using `NSDateFormatter` and then compare.

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy"];
NSArray *sortedArray = [yourArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *obj1, NSDictionary *obj2) {
    NSDate *d1 = [df dateFromString:(NSString*)[obj1 objectForKey:@"Date"]];
    NSDate *d2 = [df dateFromString:(NSString*)[obj2 objectForKey:@"Date"]];
    return [d1 compare: d2];
}];
```

Comment: This line `NSDate *d2 = [df dateFromString:(NSString*)[obj1 objectForKey:@"Date"]];` should be `NSDate *d2 = [df dateFromString:(NSString*)[obj2 objectForKey:@"Date"]];`, otherwise answer is perfact!

Comment: @balkaransingh Have you try answer? it is working properly.

Comment: @RaviPathak It was just type mistake of `obj2`.

Comment: Welcome mate, Have great day, Happy coding :

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Date"ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]; 
NSArray *sortArray = [YourArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors] ;
```

Comment: try it and then Comment here,Its worked for me @NDoc

Comment: Add date with month January and August then sort check the result.